# How to convert a JSON file to another JSON file with different approach in React

Tags: json, reactjs, tabular

I have a JSON file like this:

```
[
    {
        "quantity": "200",
        "prodType": "stock",
        "symbol": "LOL",
        "prodDesc": "Εθνική τράπεζα",
        "market": "Greece",
        "averageCost": "131,16",
        "totalCost": "123,47",
        "lastPrice": "121,123",
        "value": "123,34",
        "positionPercentage": "10",
        "valueEUR": "113,23",
        "pl": "1300",
        "plPercentage": "12",
        "plEuro": "1238",
        "results": "12-01-2017",
        "dividend": "12-03-2017",
        "isin": "1234566"
    }
]
```

Then, I create a table with the following format:

```
Quantity    Product Type    Symbol  Product Desc    Market  Average Cost    
200            stock         LOL      ET            Greece    131,16
```

But I want to display the table above with the following format:

```
Quantity     Product Type   Product Desc    Market  Average Cost
 Symbol     
  200         stock              ET         Greece     131,16
  LOL
```

I think that the best way is to create a JSON file from the fiven JSON above with the desired format. Do you know how I can do this?

Comment: The point is to modify the JSON or to manage the way it is displayed ? What do you use to render your table ?

Comment: I want to manage the way it is displayed like above. For this reason, i was thinking tha the best way is to modify the JSON. In the my list file im writing : {accounts.map((account) =>
          <AccountEntry
            key={account.quantity}
            {...account}

Comment: Also i have an account entry through which i create a single line of my table

Comment: i think u can handle this directly in ui no need of creating a new json.

Comment: But the JSON is created like the format above by default from another layer, so i was thinking to modify it

Comment: what table u r using bootstrap or any other ??

Comment: nothing special, a custom common table like this: <tr>
    <th>{quantity}</th>
    <td>{prodType}</td>
    <td>{symbol}</td>

Comment: Just a tip: If your table is dynamically loaded(f.e. every minute), fixed-data-table works really well with Reactjs.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, it should be sth like that:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(yourJsonFile);

return <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Quantity<br/>Symbol</th>
    <th>Product Type</th>
    <th>Product Desc</th>
    <th>Market</th>
    <th>Averate Cost</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>{obj.quantity}<br/>{obj.symbol}</td>
    <td>{obj.prodType}</td>
    <td>{obj.prodDesc}</td>
    <td>{obj.market}</td>
    <td>{obj.averageCost}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Karol. But this is like creating a second row. I want to display the  Quantity / Symbol in the same row

Comment: Edited. Better now?

Comment: You are awesome! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can write this in a generic way, it will populate all the rows, if u have more data, Try this:

```
 _getTableData(){
    return this.state.currentValue.map((obj, index)=>
        <tr key={index}>
            <td>{obj.quantity}<br/>{obj.symbol}</td>
            <td>{obj.prodType}</td>
            <td>{obj.prodDesc}</td>
            <td>{obj.market}</td>
            <td>{obj.averageCost}</td>
        </tr>
    );
}


render() {
    return 
      <table>
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                  <th>Quantity<br/>Symbol</th>
                  <th>Product Type</th>
                  <th>Product Desc</th>
                  <th>Market</th>
                  <th>Averate Cost</th>
              </tr>
              {this._getTableData()}
          </tbody>
      </table>
}
```

Check the working code on `jsfiddle`: https://jsfiddle.net/qswordh3/